# Creating json response from HashMap dynmically with the use of json schema

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

I have different JSON schemas each supporting different response format of different resources in RESTful Web Services. The response data is available with in the map. I need to create a json response from the map, with the help of the json schema. And i need to use Jackson.

The challenge is that , i dont know the levels of the fields in each json schema, I have only a HashMap which holds the data.

Pls suggest ways to accomplish it.

Thanks in advance.

Response Schema:

```
{
"type":"object",
"properties":
{
    "transactionId":
    {
        "description":"To uniquely identify request from a specific source.",
        "type":"string"
    },
    "productAccountInformation":
    {
        "type":"object",
        "properties":
        {
            "productId":
            {
                "description":"The unique identifier for a product",
                "type":"string"
            },
            "productAccount":
            {
                "type":"array",
                "items":
                {
                    "type":"object",
                    "properties":
                    {
                        "accountId":
                        {
                            "description":"The unique identifier for a account",
                            "type":"string"
                        },
                        "value":
                        {
                            "description":"account balance.",
                            "type":"number"
                        },
                        "noOfDecimals":
                        {
                            "description":"Number of decimal places.",
                            "type":"number"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
},
"required":["transactionId"," productAccountInformation "]
}
```

Map: 
    {
    transacionId - asdbdf123, 
    productInformation-productId - 100, 
    productInformation-productAccount-AccountId - 9941361330, 
    productInformation-productAccount-value - 5000, 
    productInformation-productAccount-noOfDecimals - 2
    }
Expected Output is:

```
{
"transactionId":"asdbdf123",
"productAccountInformation":
{
    "productId":"100",
    "productAccount":
    [
        {
            "accountId":"9941361330",
            "value":5000,
            "numberOfDecimals":2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And the above is not the only response schema we have, we will have n number of schemas. So am looking for a generic solution which generates json responses from map with the use of json schema.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish? Example of maps and expected json responses.

Comment: Nikita, i have updated the Query.